# Run-time error '1004':[ Expression.Error] The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to add Power Query code to VBA but I'm getting an error that the "Source" wasn't recognized.

```
The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly
```

I've been trying to do different spellings or playing with the commas but I'm still getting that error. Would need a second pair of eyes and any suggestions would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = ""
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Table1""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{Table.ColumnNames(Table1){0}, " & _
    "Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){1}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){2}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){3}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){4}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){5}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){6}, Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){7}, " & _
    "type datetime}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){8}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){9}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){10}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){11}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){12}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){13}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){14}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){15}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){16}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){17}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){18}, " & _
    "type any},{ Table.ColumnNames(Table1){19}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){20} , type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){21}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){22}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){23}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){24}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){25}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){25}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){26}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){27}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){28}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){29}, " & _
    "type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){30}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){31}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){32}, {Table.ColumnNames(Table1){33} ,type any}, {Table.ColumnNames(Table1){34}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){35}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){36}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){37}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){38}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){39}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){40}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){41}, " & _
    "type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){42}, type number}, {Table.ColumnNames(Table1){43}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){44}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){45}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){46}, Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){47}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){48}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){49}, Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){50}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){51}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){52}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){53}, " & _
    "type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){54}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){55}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){56}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){57}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){58}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){59} , type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){60}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){61}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){62}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){63}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){64}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){65}, " & _
    "type any},  { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){66}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){67}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){68}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){69}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){70}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){71}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){72}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){73}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){74}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){75}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){76}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){77}, " & _
    "Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){78}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){79}, Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){80}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){81}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){82}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){83}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){84} , type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){85}, Int64.Type}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){86}, type text}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){87}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){88}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){89}, " & _
    "type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){90}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){91}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){92}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){93}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){94}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){95}, type number}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){96}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){97}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){98}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){99}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){100}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){101}, " & _
    "type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){102}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){103}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){104}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){105}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){106}, type any}, { Table.ColumnNames(Table1){107}, " & _
    "type number},  {Table.ColumnNames(Table1){108}, type any}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Unpivoted Other Columns"" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#""Changed Type"", {""DPT "", ""DPT-DESC                 "", ""EMP-CD"", ""FIRST NAME          "", ""LAST NAME           "", ""S.S.N.     "", ""PAY-DT"", ""Pay Date"", ""HR-RATE ""}, ""Attribute"", ""Value"")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Unpivoted Other Columns"""
```

Comment: This error is quite generic. I was getting this error due to a syntax error farther down in my power query. I would start by simplifying the query. If you can get a small portion of it to work then you can gradually add to it until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any symbols between `let` and `Source` keywords and the string is well-formed excluding any extra symbols from it. The following example shows how to add a query to a workbook from an existing CSV file.

```
Dim mFormula As String
mFormula = _
"let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\data.txt""),null,""#(tab)"",null,1252) in Source"
query1 = ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add("query1", mFormula)
```

Comment: Thanks @Eugene for replying. I removed everything in between Let and Source and still getting the same error. `ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table1", Formula:= _
        "let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Table1""]}[Content], #""Changed Type""`